# is it correct that a class can be an instance?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

In this document
https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_introduction

it is written:

> rdfs:Resource is an instance of rdfs:Class.

[image]

however it is also written:

> This is the class of everything

[image]

is this a typo? can  a class be an instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually an interesting question. I just want to add to your comment in CaptSolo's answer:

> but can I define my custom classes as instances of an instance? ( i highly doubt that )

It's not so much a question of whether you "can" do something or not (at least not in this case), but rather whether what you do will make sense. After all the Semantic Web was built on the premise that anyone can say anything about anything. Sometimes there are consequences, which can lead to "logical" inferences about your data.

So this one makes sense:

```
:foo a rdfs:Class.
:bar a :foo.
```

while this one doesn't:

```
:george a foaf:Person.
:foo a :george.
```

Can you assert both? Technically speaking, yes, I don't think there is a triple store that will stop you from doing so. But the latter is illogical - every RDFS class is defined as the set of its instances, so you are treating a person, "George", as a concept of sorts. If your ontology or data doesn't make sense, then none will use it.

Comment: `:george  a  foaf:Person .  :foo  a  :george.` in fact makes sense. Let's say `:foo` is `:george` when he was a teenager. His `:foaf:age` is `"13 years old"` and his height is `"1.38 m"`. There are other instances of `:george`. One who just got married, one who is `a :Toddler`, one who is `a :DeadPerson`.

Answer (score 2):

All RDFS classes are instances of the `rdfs:Class` class. Since rdfs:Resource is **a class of everything** it is also a class and thus an instance of `rdfs:Class`.

This may make sense if you consider that RDFS is itself defined in RDFS. What other type would you define `rdfs:Class` to be if not the `rdfs:Class` itself?

About "can class be an instance?" - when defining an ontology you define classes as instances of `rdfs:Class` or `owl:Class`. Technically they already are instances [of these classes].

Comment: but can I define my custom classes as instances of an instance? ( i highly doubt that )

Comment: you asked specifically about RDFS and there, yes, you can (i.e. classes can also be instances of other classes). although not sure why would you want that. others will know better about OWL (where this is typically forbidden but the answer may be more complicated than that).