# Can a class in one context be considered an instance in another?

Tags: class, types, rdf, ontology

In a knowledge representation system like RDF, which is based on creating ontological hierarchies, can a class in one context be considered an instance in another?

Take the example of a triplestore which contains a library catalogue. It may contain statements such as:

```
:Book a rdfs:Class

:gullivers_travels a :Book
:moby_dick a :Book
```

This makes sense, but in another context, you may want to itemize the various editions of *Moby Dick*, and so it may *also* make sense to treat it as a class, e.g.:

```
:moby_dick a rdfs:Class

:moby_dick_manuscript a :moby_dick
:moby_dick_first_edition a :moby_dick
:moby_dick_second_edition a :moby_dick
```

Since `:moby_dick` is treated as either a class OR an instance, does that mean the two sets of statements can't co-exist without causing logical inconsistencies?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866473/is-it-correct-that-a-class-can-be-an-instance) seems to imply that this is indeed the case.

Is this a design limitation in RDF, or are there more logically-viable ways of modelling such a relationship as the one above?

Comment: In RDF? Yes, why not? In OWL 2 DL this would be also possible and is called *punning*.

Answer (score 2):

As [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw) said, why not? In fact, in RDF, **all** classes are instances (of `rdfs:Class` and of `rdfs:Resource`). In OWL 2 DL, a **class IRI** can be an **instance IRI** at the same time. However, the class identified by the class IRI cannot be an instance, and the instance identified by the instance IRI cannot be a class. That is to say that in OWL 2 DL, if an IRI identifies a class and an instance, it identifies two things, not one. A possibly surprising consequence of this is that the following is consistent:

```
ex:x1  a  owl:Thing, owl:Class .
ex:x2  a  owl:Thing, owl:Class;
    owl:sameAs  ex:x1;
    owl:disjointWith  ex:x1 .
ex:x3  a  ex:x1 .
```

So, `ex:x1` (the instance) is the same thing as `ex:x2` (the instance) but `ex:x1` (the class) is different from `ex:x2` (the class).

Comment: That is very interesting @antoine. Thanks for sharing.