# List in front of the expression in OWL?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

Is it possible to have a list in front of an expression in OWL? Something like:

```
( :Dairy :Egg :Nut ) rdfs:subClassOf :FoodGroup .
```

or:

```
:Dairy , :Egg , :Nut rdfs:subClassOf :FoodGroup .
```

Or in general, is there a syntactic sugar for a group of expressions of the type?:

```
:Diary rdfs:subClassOf :FoodGroup .
:Egg rdfs:subClassOf :FoodGroup .
:Nut rdfs:subClassOf :FoodGroup .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Turtle**

In Turtle, there are no subject lists that would be similar to [object lists](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#object-lists).

It is [possible](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#collections) to write  something like `(:a :b) rdfs:subClassOf :c`.
However, this is not equal to `:a rdfs:SubClassOf :c . :b rdfs:SubClassOf :c`.
In fact, the most useful thing you can write using [RDF list](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_collectionvocab) in subject position is `(:a :b) a rdf:List`.

I. e., there is no *syntactic* sugar.

**OWL**

Using OWL inferencing capabilities, it is possible to achieve something like this.

One can declare an inverse property and then use Turtle object lists in serialization:

```
:inverseProperty owl:inverseOf :directProperty .
:c :inverseProperty :a, :b .
```

[image: inverse]

**Limitations**

However, this doesn't work for `rdfs:subClassOf`. Object properties connect individuals, not classes. Something like `:c rdfs:superClassOf :a, :b` will be treated as related to the same-name *individuals*.

[image: punning]

This is how [OWL punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning) works (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270563/7879193) eye-opening answer).

For the particular case of `rdfs:subClassOf`, write `[ owl:unionOf (:a :b) ] rdfs:subClassOf :c`,
if you don't need simply `:c owl:unionOf (:a :b)` or `:c owl:disjointUnionOf (:a :b)`.

[image: gci]

Unfortunately, [general class inclusion](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1288) axioms can not be saved in the Manchester syntax.

Comment: BTW: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sparql-dev/2015JanMar/0030.html. And obviously, you can write something like `?c ^rdfs:subClassOf :a, :b` in SPARQL.