# RDF: How to specify properties for a set of individuals?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

Is there a good/recommended pattern or method to set the value of a property for a group of instances of the same class? For example: suppose I have a dataset about people. Could I define a group of individuals and state that the whole group has foaf:firstName = "Bob", instead of repeating that for all individuals?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342469, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835958

Comment: It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075078/is-it-possible-to-make-property-assertions-on-class-level-in-owl-2 has an answer to a very similar question.

Comment: Thanks to all commenters for the useful references. Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075078/is-it-possible-to-make-property-assertions-on-class-level-in-owl-2 answers my question.